# How to remove URL encoding in my querystring using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have search textbox. When the user enters some text my querystring shows the text with ASCII characters like `%20` and `%3F`. I want to show this text in one of my textboxes without any ASCII codes like normal HTML text. How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: That's normal URL-encoding, it's required for any special characters in a URL query string. The server will automatically decode it.

Comment: I am showing of that value in textbox which is encoded. I need to decode it in the textbox.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `decodeURIComponent()`:

```js
var querystring = "?foo=bar%20baz";
console.log(decodeURIComponent(querystring));
```

[decodeURIComponent MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `URLSearchParams` along with `decodeURIComponent`.

Personally I prefer `URLSearchParams`.

From my testing, `decodeURIComponent` literally just strips/replaces the URI encodes, but `URLSearchParams` only returns the values of specific `querystrings` and allows methods to get specific key/value pairs like below.

Example:

```js
var querystring = "?foo=bar%20baz";
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(querystring)
console.log('decoded:');
console.log(decoded)
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(querystring);
var foo = urlParams.get('foo');
console.log('foo:');
console.log(foo)
```